# amazon redshift utility - view v_generate_tbl_ddl not returning primary key constraint in ddl after table has been populated

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm using the amazon redshift utility v_generate_tbl_ddl to generate a table ddl, but have found that after my table has been populated the primary key constraint doesn't show (example below)

Structure table creation:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
CREATE TABLE temp_table 
(
  id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  text   VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
DISTSTYLE ALL SORTKEY (id);
```

Checking the ddl after the table has been created shows the primary key constraint is present:

```
SELECT *
FROM admin.v_generate_tbl_ddl
WHERE tablename = 'temp_table'
AND   schemaname = 'myschema';
```

Inserting some data:

```
COPY temp_table
FROM 's3://s3_bucket_location/manifest_file_temp_table.json' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...' DELIMITER AS '|' gzip manifest
```

Checking again the ddl and now the primary key constraint isn't there

```
SELECT *
FROM admin.v_generate_tbl_ddl
WHERE tablename = 'temp_table'
AND   schemaname = 'myschema';
```

I'm sure the primary key is still there as I've doubled checked using:

```
SELECT pg_table_def.tablename,
       pg_table_def.column
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'
AND   tablename = 'temp_table_pkey';
```

Digging into the sql of v_generate_tbl_ddl it is this section that isn't returning rows after the table has been populated, but I can't figure out why this stops returning rows? Any help here would be appreciated

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname,
       c.relname AS tablename,
       200000000 + CAST(con.oid AS INT) AS seq,
       ('\t,' + pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid))::CHARACTER VARYING (500) AS ddl
FROM pg_constraint AS con
  INNER JOIN pg_class AS c
          ON c.relnamespace = con.connamespace
         AND c.relfilenode = con.conrelid
  INNER JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind = 'r'
AND   pg_get_constraintdef (con.oid) NOT LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY%'
AND   c.relname = 'temp_table'
ORDER BY seq
```

Comment: Check where tablename='zzzzzzzz'